# Devise - Insert data into HAS_ONE related model during sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User model, that has_one Profile.

Profile is the place where all the user stuff is saved (name, phone, address, state, etc).

During sign up I need to let user fill in those fields.

Tried to do nested fields but it doesn't really work and I don't really understand why.

Does anyone have similar code examples? Can't find anything in Internet.

```
Candidate has_one :profile
Profile belongs_to :user
```

Registration form:

```
= simple_form_for(:candidate,
                          as: Candidate,
                          url: candidate_registration_path) do |f|
          = f.simple_fields_for :profile do |profile|
            = profile.input :first_name
            = profile.input :last_name
          = f.input :email
          = f.input :password
          = f.input :password_confirmation
          = f.submit 'Start Building', class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

Didn't do anything with controllers except this:

```
def configure_devise_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
      u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation,
               profile_attributes: [:first_name, :last_name])
    end
  end
```

Comment: a code sample would be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say it doesn't work do you mean that it doesn't save? Or it doesn't show the fields?

In the latter case, you would have to build the blank profile in the registrations controller before the action is hit. So basically override the devise controller and do something like this:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def new
    user = build_resource({})
    user.build_profile if user.profile.blank?
    respond_with self.resource
  end

end
```

routes.rb

```
  devise_for :candidates, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
```

Candidate.rb

```
has_one :profile
accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
```

and make sure the code you have written above for strong parameters is in your application_controller.

This is also assuming your devise model is called "Candidate"

Comment: The only problem is that I'm not using Devise's default new_session_path. I have a form, which I submit into sessions_path via POST request.

Answer (score 0):

Check the params in your log. Try creating a user in console using those params. Do you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile` on your user model?